# Element cannot locate with the text- selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on selenium webdriver and the using the language Java.

```
Log.info("Clicking on To weekrange dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor25 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor25.executeScript("document.getElementById('toWeekYear).style.display='block';");
Select select25 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("toWeekYear")));
select25.selectByVisibleText("2011");
JavascriptExecutor executor26 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor26.executeScript("document.getElementById('toWeekYear).style.display='block';");
Select select26 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(" toWeek")));
select26.selectByVisibleText(" W 5");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

In the above code, am trying to select the week range and it is in the form to select year-2011 and week-W 5. This values are selecting from the dropdown. The problem is while selecting 1st dropdown it is selecting the year and while trying to select the second drop down am getting the error Cannot locate element with text:  W 1

Here is the HTML tag:

```
<select id="fromWeekYear" style="width:60px" name="fromWeekYear">
<option value="2010"> 2010</option>
<option value="2011"> 2011</option>
<option value="2012"> 2012</option>
<option selected="" value="2013"> 2013</option>
</select>
<select id="fromWeek" style="width:60px" name="fromWeek">
<option value="1"> W 1</option>
<option value="2"> W 2</option>
<option value="3"> W 3</option>
<option value="4"> W 4</option>
<option value="5"> W 5</option>
```

and

```
<select id="toWeekYear" style="width:60px" name="toWeekYear">
<option value="2010"> 2010</option>
<option value="2011"> 2011</option>
<option value="2012"> 2012</option>
<option selected="" value="2013"> 2013</option>
</select>
<select id="toWeek" style="width:60px" name="toWeek">
<option value="1"> W 1</option>
<option value="2"> W 2</option>
<option value="3"> W 3</option>
<option value="4"> W 4</option>
<option value="5"> W 5</option>
```

Here is my fromweek javascript:

```
Log.info("Clicking on From weekrange dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor23 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor23.executeScript("document.getElementById('fromWeekYear').style.display='block';");

Select select23 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fromWeekYear")));
select23.selectByVisibleText("2011");
JavascriptExecutor executor24 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Thread.sleep(6000);
executor24.executeScript("document.getElementById('fromWeek').style.display='block';");
Select select24 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fromWeek")));
select24.selectByVisibleText(" W 1");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Comment: Looks like, some delay in loading 2nd drop-down(based on 1st drop-down selection). Please introduce about 2 second wait time before trying to select 2nd drop-down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fromWeekYear")).selectByValue("2010");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("toWeek")).selectByValue("1");
```

Value is single, use value.

If by text, your text has space:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fromWeekYear")).selectByVisibleText(" 2010");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("toWeek")).selectByVisibleText(" W 1");
```

Other issue is that maybe your space is (& nbsp;)

Answer (score 1):

You have some spacing issues:

`driver.findElement(By.id(" toWeek")));`

Should not have a space in the id:

`driver.findElement(By.id("toWeek")));`

Comment: Thanks. But am getting the problem in the fromweek itself

Comment: Can you post the Javascript that is accessing `fromWeek` then?

Comment: Any one can give me solution for this issue

Comment: I don't see any Javascript attempting to access `fromWeek`, if your problem is with that select, please post the JS accessing it

Comment: I added JS above. please give me solution