# How to Automate cascading drop downs using selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing issue while automating cascading drop down. Functionality is like this: On clicking drop down list and selecting one value, it will open another drop down according to the value selected in parent drop down.

Please find screenshots here: [CLICK HERE](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AlB69WNspp0thzBvv-ONwVYT3p85)

Here is my code:

```
Utility.SelectDropdown(driver, "//div[3]/div/div/select", "Test 1");                
Utility.SelectDropdown(driver, "//div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/select", "Test 2");
Utility.SelectDropdown(driver, "//div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/select", "Test 3");
```

Utility class:

```
public static void SelectDropdown(WebDriver driver,String xpath,String value){
            WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
            Select dropdown=new Select(ele);
            dropdown.selectByVisibleText(value);
```

I tried this using Wait and tab out, But it didn't work.
It is selecting value in first drop down but unable to load child drop down. Hence I am getting error message like this:

`" Cannot locate element with text: Test 2."
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'`

Here is HTML of drop down:[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufoXl.png)

Suggestions for this query will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20462732/1335594 Check this post which possibly deals with a similar issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'unable to load child drop down'. Do you mean values in the sub drop-downs are not getting populated / the sub drop-down controls are disabled?

Comment: No, I mean complete drop down is not appearing at all. Manually, when we click on any value from first drop down, it will open new drop down field. Here my code is able to select value from first drop down, But not able to open next drop down

Comment: I have added screenshots. You will get an idea about its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue was resolved with the help of keys function.

```
WebElement element8 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("manPosDropD1_xpath"))));
        element8.click();
        element8.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        element8.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Thank you.